# How to detected if application is closed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have an app that receives from the Broadcastreceiver to fetch new data from the web(json), when my app is running while it fetches; everything runs well, when the app is closed it crashes "Your app stopped working". Even the following good to check if my app is in the foreground doesn't work. 
i want it so if the app is closed, not running, to call an intent to open the app for it not to crash, so how do I check if application is closed?

My code;

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static long alarmTime = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



    if (isAppForground(context)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "APP IN FOREGROUND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Intent intentActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intentActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intentActivity);
        Toast.makeText(context, "APP NOT RUNNING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //set new alarm for next tuesday
    UpcomingFragment.getInstance().setAlarm(-1);
    //updates the current json
    UpcomingFragment.getInstance().update();


}

public static long getAlermTimeInMillis(){
    return alarmTime;
}

public boolean isAppForground(Context mContext) {

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(mContext.getPackageName())) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Add crash logs from the device

Comment: Maybe sometime's wrong with my Android studio?

Comment: use this command to save it  in a file
adb logcat > crashlogs.txt

Comment: where do I execute this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same question , and I was stuck on it for **days**. Luckily, on day 3, I found a solution that works.

```
public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
    if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        //SCREEN IS NOT SHOWING
}
```

This `onTrimMemory` method is extremely useful. It is supposed to be used to **optimize** your app in memory, but we can use it to our advantage like this also!

Comment: Ok I marked it my friend, so where do I call this method? In my OnRecieve()? And then where do I call my intents?

Comment: @MadBoy You don't need to call it! That's the cool part, it's like a listener. As soon as user leaves, it will get called by itself!

Comment: And if it returns "true" that means that the app is running or closed?

Comment: @MadBoy It doesn't return a boolean. Instead, we compare it like this: `level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN`

Comment: @MadBoy That says, "If the user has left the screen"

Comment: Thx, so I just call this method in my onCreate in my MainAcgivity and that's it? No need to change the code in my OnReceive()?

Comment: @MadBoy You don't need to call it! That's the cool part, it's like a listener. As soon as user leaves, it will get called by itself!

Comment: So I just need to define the method? And that's it?

Comment: And do I keep onReceive() as it is?

Comment: @MadBoy Yes, onRecieve() doesnt mater

Comment: it works only if the app is totally removed from the memory stack, what if it is hidden but still in the memory stack, I was testing your method on a Lollipop and Nougat OS